# Create or replace node in an XML without root in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I have an XML file like this:

```
<Something>....</Something>
<Another>....</Another>
<Other>...</Other>
```

This XML file does not have a root element (I know that this is a wrong XML format).

I need to create or replace (if it already exists) a node in this XML, but I can't work with `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` because they need a root element to work, and I can't add a root element to this XML because I can't change more code in the Application (Windows forms application).

What are my options to perform this?

Edit 1:
Using @chridam's sample, I have this method, but it replaces the entire XML. What do I need to change?

```
public void ReEscribirNodoXML(string pathXml, string nodoName, string nodeContent)
{
    if (File.Exists(pathXml))
    {
        XmlValidatingReader vr = new XmlValidatingReader(pathXml, XmlNodeType.Element, null);
        while (vr.Read())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("NodeType: {0} NodeName: {1}", vr.NodeType, vr.Name);
        }

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;

        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(pathXml, settings);
        writer.WriteStartElement(nodoName);
        writer.WriteRaw(nodeContent);
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.Flush();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("I#Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: How `.....` looks like? Is it multi-line xml data or each element is represented as single line in file?

Comment: The `.....` are single line but the new element (or maybe is already there and it should be replaced) is a multi-line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use Xdocument by simply supplying a framework to work with, then *discarding that framework when done*.

Here is the fragment going in, a change made, a new node added and a fragment going out:

```
var fragment = @"<Something>abc</Something>
<Another>def</Another>
<Other>ghi</Other>";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse("<TempRoot>" + fragment + "</TempRoot>");

xDoc.Descendants("Another").First().Value = "Jabberwocky";
xDoc.Root.Add(new XElement("Omega", "Man"));

var fragOut = 
   string.Join(Environment.NewLine, xDoc.Root
                                        .Elements()
                                        .Select (ele => ele.ToString()));

Console.WriteLine (fragOut);
/* Prints out
<Something>abc</Something>
<Another>Jabberwocky</Another>
<Other>ghi</Other>
<Omega>Man</Omega>
*/
```

Comment: Seems pretty good to me. One thing to note - there exists `xDoc.Root` which you can use instead of `xDoc.Element("Root")`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy yours is an excellent point. I will update it to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocumentfragment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx to work with such a fragment e.g.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDocumentFragment frag = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
frag.InnerXml = @"<Something>....</Something>
<Another>....</Another>
<Other>...</Other>";
```

Now you can access nodes in the document fragment with `ChildNodes`, `SelectNodes`, `SelectSingleNode` and so on and manipulate nodes with the DOM methods (like `AppendChild`) or properties (like `InnerText`).

Comment: I keep having the problem that the XML is in a file and not in a string... how do i open that file and get the string to perform the code you have?

Comment: Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx e.g. `string fragXml = File.ReadAllText("fragment.xml");` then `frag.InnerXml = fragXml;`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to  manipulate XML using DOM your option is text manipulation tools. Try 
regular expressions to locate the node you  need and then remove  the  text using string  manipulation  routines.
However adding  root element to the source text is an easy way to  have  the DOM working.
You can remove it later , after processing the XML.