# How to parse a xml document without a root node?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an xml document which **has no root node.** It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Line>
        <City>Paris</City>
        <Country>France</Country>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <City>Lissabon</City>
        <Country>Spain</Country>
    </Line>
```

No I want to read `Line` by `Line` and write the contents to a database. However, `XmlDocument` seems to insist that there must exist a root node. How can I process this file?

Comment: You can add root element, please see this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21857486/12282249

Comment: Can you post what have you tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse it as an XML document, you can add a root node like Denis proposed in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62006717/how-to-parse-a-xml-document-without-a-root-node/62006993#comment109668209_62006717).

If you would just like to read each line and write it to a database, you can handle the file like an ordinary (text) file and read its contents line by line using a `StreamReader`.

This would look something like this:

```cs
string line;  

// Read the file and process it line by line.  
var reader = new StreamReader(FILEPATH);  
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)  
{
    // Depending on what you need, you could strip the XML tags  
    // And write the line to the database  
}  

reader.Close();
```

Comment: No, sorry, with "line by line" I meant the "Line" tags. I don't want to write the physical lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (simple WinForms app with a button and a rich text box to display output for testing):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp11
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings
            {
                ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
            };
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"c:\ab\countries.xml", settings))
            {
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.Name != "Line") // Ignore the <Line> nodes
                    {
                        switch (reader.NodeType)
                        {
                            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                                sb.Append(string.Format("{0}:", reader.Name));
                                break;

                            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                                sb.Append(string.Format(" {0}{1}", reader.Value, Environment.NewLine));
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be not the best solution, but you could create a `List` (or array) from your XML and insert missing nodes:

```
// Read lines into List
var list = File.ReadLines("doc.xml").ToList();
// Insert missing nodes
list.Insert(1, "<root>"); // Use 1, because 0 is XML directive
list.Insert(list.Count, "</root>"); //Add closing tag to the end
// Create final XML string with LINQ
var xml_str = list.Aggregate("", (acc, s) => acc + s);
// Having a string, we can create, for instance, XElement (or XDocument)
var xml = XElement.Parse(xml_str);
Console.WriteLine(xml.Element("Line").Element("City").Value);
//Output: Paris
```